# Probability by similarity between two dictionaries w/ Naive Bayes

Tags: python, machine-learning

There are two dictionaries that i would like to compare the 'keys' and 'values'.

```
Dic1 = {    
    'FOSF SER': 0,
    'ECA': 1,
    'GL': 1,
    'GL H2': 1,
    'GL JEJ': 0
}

Dic2 = {
    'Diabetes': {'GL' : 1, 'GL JEJ': 1, 'HBA GLC': 1, 'GL 2H': 1},
    'Hipotireioidismo': {'FOSF SER': 1, 'ECA': 1, 'TSH 21-54': 1, 'TSH 55-87': 1},
    'Hipertireioidismo': {'FOSF SER': 0, 'TSH 21-54': 0, 'TSH 55-87': 0}
}
```

In other words, i would like Python to make the following prediction:

Among the items in the dictionary 'Dic2', which one has more similarity with the dictionary 'Dic1'? What is the probability (%) of each of the items listed in Dic2 being what Dic1 refers to?

I wish the output was something like this:

```
"Diabetes: x.xx%"
"Hipotireoidismo: x.xx%"
"Hipertireoidismo: x.xx%"
```

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to compare the values between the lists and output how probable the disease (x) is based on the symptoms (y). The percentage value is calculated based on how many of the symptoms are fulfilled and does not take into account negative symptoms or missed symptoms though that could easily be added in - its just a starting point for you to get the ball rolling

```
for x in Dic2:
count = 0
Dic3 = Dic2[x]
for y in Dic3:
    if(y in Dic1):
        if(Dic3[y] == Dic1[y]):
            count += 1
percentage = (count/float(len(Dic3)))*100
print(x + " : " + str(percentage) +"%")
```

Comment: Thank you casualcoder, it looks very efficient. I tried to implement this code in my code but it is returning 0.00% with all diseases... Can you help me?

Comment: I wrote this up on mobile, probably there's a syntax error due to which count is never incremented, I'll take a proper look at it when I get to my system

Comment: @MarshallVegas i fixed the issue, i forgot that for-in gives the keys not values of the keys the new code works and gives percentages out give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

For this problem I wouldn't use SkLearn. Reather with a simple nested loops it is possible to solve it.

Assuming that you just want to find the Dictionary that has the most number of items equal to your Query Dictionary (Dic1) divided by the number of items in the Query (the similarity) the simplest answer that I can think of is:

```
nDic1 = len(Dic1)*1.
for item in Dic2:
   match = 0
   iDic = Dic2[item]
   for i in iDic:
      if i in Dic1:
         if iDic[i] == Dic1[i]:
            match +=1
   print("{}: {}%".format(item, match*100/nDic1))
```

The  printed result in this case is:

```
Diabetes: 20.0%
Hipotireioidismo: 20.0%
Hipertireioidismo: 20.0%
```